# my effort to prove a relation about continuous function and countabe sets

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

For $n>1$, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there are at most two values $x\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f^{-1}(x)$ is countable.

My effort:

Suppose $a<b<c$ have the property that $f^{-1}(a)$, $B\triangleq f^{-1}(b)$ and $f^{-1}(c)$ are countable.

Let $\alpha\in(a,b)$ and $\beta\in(b,c)$, and let $x\in f^{-1}(\alpha)$ and $y\in f^{-1}(\beta)$. Since $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n-B$ which is path-connected since $B$ is countable, there exists a continuous function $r:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n-B$ s.t. $r(0)=x$ and $r(1)=y$. Thus, we have the composition $f\circ r:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}-\{b\}$ with $f\circ r(0)=\alpha$ and $f\circ r(1)=\beta$.

Suppose $f$ is continuous. Then, $f\circ r$ is continuous. This implies $f\circ r([0,1])$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}-\{b\}$, which is a contradiction. (Because define a function $g: f\circ r([0,1])\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ as $g(t)=\left\{
             \begin{array}{ll}
             1, &  t>b \\
             0, &  t<b
             \end{array}
   \right.$.  $g$ is continuous with $g(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\beta)=1$. Thus, $f\circ r([0,1])$ is not connected, which is a contradiction. )

But I never use the property that $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(c)$ are countable. Is there something wrong?

Update: It seems I should change $\alpha$ to $a$ and $\beta$ to $c$.

Comment: By countable do you mean countably infinite? If empty set is considered  countable this result is obviously false: Just take $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that your proof correctly shows the following stronger statement: if $a$ and $c$ are values of $f(x)$ and $a<b<c$, then $f^{-1}(b)$ is uncountable.

It follows from this statement that the only possible values $v$ of $f$ for which $f^{-1}(v)$ is countable and nonempty are the global minimum of $f$ and the global maximum of $f$.

Comment: Right. But I cannot find what is wrong...

Comment: My intention was to clarify that you didn't do anything wrong.